# Error when I hit node js api through angular 8: Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'name' cannot be nul

Tags: node.js, angular

I am very new to node and angular, I am trying to insert data into `mysql` I have `node api` when I test this api through `postman` record get inserted successfully, but when I call node api through angular I am getting error.

```
angular CLI: 7.3.1
Node: 10.15.0
```

**nodejs**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT, POST');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
     res.sendStatus(200);
   }
   else {
     next();
   }
  });

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'auth'
});

conn.connect((err) =>{
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Mysql Connected...');
});

conn.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("[mysql error]",err);
})

app.post('/add/',(req, res) => {
  let data = {name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password, contact: req.body.contact};
  let sql = "INSERT INTO registration SET ?";
  let query = conn.query(sql, data,(err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
  });
});

app.listen(3000,() =>{
  console.log('Server started on port 3000...');
});
```

**angular: sign-up.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {


private userDetails = User;

userEmails = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$")]),

    firstName: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ]),

    password: new FormControl('', [

      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}")

    ]),

    confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ]),

    contact: new FormControl('', [

      Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(10),
      Validators.minLength(10),
      Validators.pattern("^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$")
    ])
}, 

{
    validators: CustomValidators.passwordMatchValidator
}
);
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  }
   get validations() {
     return this.userEmails.controls;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onDisplay() {
    console.log(this.userEmails.value);
    this.authService.registerUser(this.userEmails.value)
    .subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => console.log(err)
    )  
  }
}
```

**angular: auth.service**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private registerUrl = "http://localhost:3000/add/";
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


registerUser(register:User) {
  console.log(register);
  return this.http.post<any>(this.registerUrl, register);

}

}
```

**ERROR**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/add/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/add/", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/add/: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
```

I don't even know this error is because of angular or because of node, I searched in google and get it is because of `CROS` but I also add `CROS header` to the server side but still no luck, Also add firefox extension `CROS Everywhere` but still no luck.

**error getting from node terminal**

```
 throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'name' cannot be null
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (F:\angular\New folder\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (F:\angular\New folder\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (F:\angular\New folder\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (F:\angular\New folder\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (F:\angular\New folder\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (F:\angular\New folder\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\angular\New folder\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\angular\New folder\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
```

Is is logical or syntax issue or is it because of version ? please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a problem with you MySQL insert statement based on the following error reported on your node server log. It seems like

> Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'name' cannot be null

based on your code, CORS should work provided your client is running on port 4200.

If you want to do a quick test, try removing your MySQL insert code and simply return a dummy object back like the following example.

```
app.post('/add/',(req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": "added 1 row"}));
});
```

please let me know if you still don't get response back in your angular app.

Also, going back to your original error, it seems like you're not referring correct name in node server method [i.e. req.body.name seems not present, check your

> userEmail.value

object in angular form.

Comment: Really really thank you brother, as you said I was not referring the correct name I correct it and now its working fine.

Comment: great! Keep going